# Vue SVG/HTML Attribute Interpolation

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

Is this the correct way to interpolate a value into a svg(html) attribute with Vue ?
It works, but I'm asking since it's nowhere stated in their guide.

```
<svg :stroke-width="`${strokeWidth} px`" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but you'll need to add a computed property to return the formatted string for the `stroke-width` attribute.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes
Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes. Instead, use a v-bind directive:

```
<div v-bind:id="dynamicId"></div>
```

So in your case, assuming your `strokeWidth` is data:

```
<template>
  <svg :stroke-width="strokeWidthAttr" >
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      strokeWidth: 2
    }
  },
  computed: {
    strokeWidthAttr () {
      return `${this.strokeWidth} px`
    }
  }
}
</script>
```